# Let two long running processes "talk" to each other by text files

Tags: java, communication

I have two (Java) processes on different JVMs running repeatedly. The first one regularly finds some "information" and needs to store it somewhere. The second process regularly reads this information to handle it. The intervals are more or less random, so process 1 may find three pieces of information until process 2 reads them or vice versa.

My approach is to write this information to text files. But I am afraid that appending and reading the text files accidentally happens at the same time so that I run into locks. But writing a new text file for each piece of information seems like overkill.

What would be a better solution?

EDIT: I am sorry, I did not make clear: The java processes run in different JVMs. They cannot see each other directly.

Comment: Don't add, append.

Comment: They run repeatedly or continually?

Comment: This sounds like producer-consumer problem. See the example: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javaexamples/thread_procon.htm

Comment: @Ambrish See my EDIT.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils Process 1 is called by an event (repeatedly). Process 2 is restarted once it ended, so it is a more or less continually running process.

Comment: Are you able to communicate via sockets? File handling seems always a bit fragile and using sockets you could use a blocking read until a new message has been received.

Comment: @Smutje: It may take 30 minutes between process 1 writing the information and process 2 reading it. I doubt you could use sockets for that.

Comment: Why? On start, 2 opens a (server) socket on port X and on event, 1 tries to open a (client) socket and write to port X. If not possible (2 is down), wait and repeat. If possible, write to port X and go on - like a chat or anything similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get this to work, provided you are careful with file handling and you don't have a high update rate e.g. 10 updates per second.

Note: you could do it with file renaming instead of locks.

> What would be a better solution?

Just about anything, SO is not for recommending things, but in this case I could recommend just about anything without more specific requirements. I could for example recommend my library [Chronicle Queue](https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Queue) because I wrote it and I sure it could do what you want, however there are many possible alternatives.

> I am sending about one line of text every minute.

So you can write a temporary file for each message, rename it when finished.  The consumer can have a directory watcher so it knows as soon as you have done this. The consumer could delete the file when done.  This has an overhead but it would be less than 10 ms.

If you want to keep a record of all messages, the producer can also write to a log file.

Comment: Thank you, but this seems to be too complicated for my problem. I am sending about one line of text every minute.